# Who will call "Visualizer_process" in Android

Tags: android, audio

I want to capture the audio wave frame from the audio buffer, I found **android.media.audiofx.Visualizer** can do such thing, but it can only returns partial and low quality audio content

I found **android.media.audiofx.Visualizer** will call to the function **Visualizer_command(VISUALIZER_CMD_CAPTURE)** at **android4.0\frameworks\base\media\libeffects\visualizer**

I found the function **Visualizer_process** will make the audio content to low quality. I want to rewrite the **Visualizer_process** , and want to find who will call **Visualizer_process**, but I cannot find the caller from Android source code, can anyone help me ?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AudioFlinger::PlaybackThread::threadLoop`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/Threads.cpp?h=kitkat#n2374) calls [`AudioFlinger::EffectChain::process_l`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/Effects.cpp?h=kitkat#n1289), which calls [`AudioFlinger::EffectModule::process`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/Effects.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n249), which finally calls the actual effect's `process` function.

As you can see in `AudioFlinger::EffectModule::process`, there's the call

```
int ret = (*mEffectInterface)->process(mEffectInterface,
                                       &mConfig.inputCfg.buffer,
                                       &mConfig.outputCfg.buffer);
```

`mEffectInterface` is an `effect_handle_t`, which is an `effect_interface_s**`. The `effect_interface_s` struct (defined [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/libhardware/tree/include/hardware/audio_effect.h?h=kitkat#n291)) contains a number of function pointers (`process`, `command`, ...). These are filled out with pointers the actual effect's functions when the effect is loaded. The effects provide these pointers through a struct (in `EffectVisualizer` it's [`gVisualizerInterface`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libeffects/visualizer/EffectVisualizer.cpp?h=kitkat#n676)).

Note that the exact location of these functions may differ between different Android releases. So if you're looking at Android 4.0 you might find some of them in AudioFlinger.cpp (or somewhere else).

Comment: thanks your help. 
BTW, Do you know which code maps the function "Visualizer_process(...)" to "process(...)" and "Visualizer_command(...)" to "command(...)" ?